# AWS S3 uploaded files not showing

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am using golang sdk to upload files to a bucket on amazon S3.The response gives no error and the file is uploaded successfully. My problem is when I am listing the objects of the bucket in the same region in which I have uploaded a new `.jpg` file. I am getting same files list with no new file added to the Bucket. I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is the code that I am using to list objects inside the bucket.

```
input := &s3.ListObjectsInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("Bucket Name"),
}
result2, err := svc.ListObjects(input)
if err != nil {
    if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        switch aerr.Code() {
        case s3.ErrCodeNoSuchBucket:
            fmt.Println(s3.ErrCodeNoSuchBucket, aerr.Error())
        default:
            fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
        }
    } else {
        // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
        // Message from an error.
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    return
}
log.Println("Bucket List", result2)
```

Comment: What is it showing in the AWS console?

Comment: Triple-check the bucket name is the same on the upload & download.

Comment: @CharlieFish I cannot access AWS console. I just have access keys that I am using with sdk

Comment: @Adrian I have triple checked the bucket. I thinks there is a policy that is applied to bucket to upload not more than a bucket count. But I am not sure if this is the problem because the api response shown successfully uploaded bucket

Comment: @Himanshu I think it’d throw an error. But are you sure you have permissions to upload AND get files? Sometimes those permissions can be strange and produce unexpected results if you don’t have them setup correctly.

Comment: @CharlieFish yes I have listed the objects before uploading a new object and then listed objects again but did not see any changes

Comment: @Himanshu Honestly at this point it’s blind guesses. If there are no errors and you see other objects getting returned but not the one you uploaded we are blind to the issue. You haven’t really provided enough detail to be able to help us solve your problem. Sadly I don’t know what other information you can provide. I mean if I was in your position I would just rely on the standard debugging techniques and maybe consider reaching out to AWS support

Comment: @CharlieFish let me check it once again if i could get more information to recreate the issue. Well thanks for your time.

Comment: I had something similar where I had files being uploaded (in my case from signed URLs) and returning 204 success responses but not showing up in the bucket. 

It turns out **I had a forward slash at the start of the object key**, and instead of parsing it like a file system (ie start at root) it created an entire duplicate folder structure in a folder in the root called `/`, and put my files there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

s3 is eventually consistent and may not show an object that has been recently written in a list, even from within the same zone:

> Amazon S3 achieves high availability by replicating data across
> multiple servers within Amazon's data centers. If a PUT request is
> successful, your data is safely stored. However, information about the
> changes must replicate across Amazon S3, which can take some time, and
> so you might observe the following behaviors:
>
> A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately lists keys
> within its bucket. Until the change is fully propagated, the object
> might not appear in the list.
>
> A process replaces an existing object and immediately attempts to read
> it. Until the change is fully propagated, Amazon S3 might return the
> prior data.
>
> A process deletes an existing object and immediately attempts to read
> it. Until the deletion is fully propagated, Amazon S3 might return the
> deleted data.
>
> A process deletes an existing object and immediately lists keys within
> its bucket. Until the deletion is fully propagated, Amazon S3 might
> list the deleted object.

see [S3 developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html)

There is a polling Go AWS API call "func (*S3) WaitUntilObjectExists" which keeps looking for a file until it appears or a time out happens

**Update** [s3 is now strongly consistent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html#ConsistencyModel) thanks to @Tensiba for pointing this out!

> Amazon S3 provides strong read-after-write consistency for PUT and
> DELETE requests of objects in your Amazon S3 bucket in all AWS
> Regions. This behavior applies to both writes to new objects as well
> as PUT requests that overwrite existing objects and DELETE requests.
> In addition, read operations on Amazon S3 Select, Amazon S3 access
> controls lists (ACLs), Amazon S3 Object Tags, and object metadata (for
> example, the HEAD object) are strongly consistent.

Comment: It was some kind of permission issue because when I tried to upload the file in another bucket it returns with information of uploaded file including the location on aws s3. And when I try to list the objects inside that bucket it shows the updated list with new file.

Comment: but surely if you had a permission error the upload script would have thrown an error?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't get an error while uploading the file. But now my problem is solved by using another bucket.

Comment: What is a reasonable time for consistency to be achieved? I guess it's some sort of statistical distribution strictly speaking, so there's no simple answer. I am seeing objects not there 10-15s after they're written, what are the chances of that happening (because of this)?

Comment: Just for the information, since december 2020 S3 is now strongly consistent and no more eventually consistent: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/

Comment: @AnthonyOkoth do a proof of concept and make a question